How to upgrade a Postgresql logical replica that's also publishing to another database without pausing writes?
I have a setup where my application connects to a PostgreSQL 16 server (server A) and there is a PostgreSQL 12 server (server B) that's a logical replica of server A and is also a source for PeerDB syncing that uses a logical replication slot:

I want to upgrade server B to PostgreSQL 16 or 17 without having to restart the logical replication process to PeerDB from scratch (since the database is quite big, about 8TB). How can I do it?
1 way I can think of is to pause all writes to server A, run pg_upgrade on server B and then recreate the replication slots but I want to do it without doing the pause if possible.

Base on your diagram, upgarding Postgres in Server B affecting to

Logical Replication from Server A to Server B.
Logical Replication from Server B to PeerDB

I think you can achieve a minimum downtime by using logical replication. The downside is to increase the hardware cost. Here is my suggestion in high-level (by passed the analysis step)
Step 1: On Server B > new PG 17

Create a new Postgres v17 running on port 15432. Server B has 2 PG instances with port 5432 and port 15432.
It is up to about DATA DISK management.

Step 2: Setup new Logical repliaction to new PG 17

Source: Server A
Target: new PG 17 on port 15432 in Server B

Step 3: Switch Peer DB to new PG 17

It requires downtime here to stop all WRITE to Server A to ensure the data consistency on both PG 5432 and PG 15432 in Server B

Switch Peer DB to new PG 17 (up to you to update the port number)

I would suggest to keep both PG 17 and PG 12 running for a while in case of rollback.


Step 4: Post-upgrade

Cleanup old PG v12 in Server B

Cleanup old LR from PG v16 to PG v12 and etc.



thanks, I have thought about this option too but pausing writes to server A is not something I'm allowed to do.

In that case, I think you should consider disable-logical-replication between the source and target. This does not stop writing to server A.
